is there a way to use a reference image that is missaligned like the image is in 3d shading [read body]
so let's say my image is a wolf and the reference is not in a typical format (I don't know the term for this) and the image is a little bit off to the side and rotated a little bit
as you can see below

for more context I mean creating a 3d model from this image

You have the scale of the thing the same so that is a plus, and your front and side view of the head is working for you. I'd suggest this is more of a reference to look at the head and the height and then work out length from feel. Mostly this is going to be usable only if you are good at modeling from multiple references already.

You'll never be sure that you'll get the length of the body right

yep that's what i was think and I am a starter for modeling I only up to this point been using blender for animations not actual modeling

just look at dogs with similar proportions, for example an Azawakh
